# Can I attach 3 NICs, each with its own public IP to a vm on Azure?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to attach 3 NICs to a vm on Azure. Also according to our requirements, each NIC should have a public IP associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here..https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/multiple-vm-nics-and-network-virtual-appliances-in-azure/

You can have multiple NICs but..

Internet-facing VIP is only supported on the “default” NIC, and there is only one VIP mapped to the IP of the default NIC. The additional NICs cannot be used in a Load Balance set.

So, apparently not.

Edit...although reading the comments

Hi Ivan,

Yes, multiple external IP addresses for a Multi-NIC VM is on the roadmap.

Thanks,
Yushun

That was a year ago..

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.